# Rendering React on Node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

```
                                  # Rendering React on Node.js server? #
```

================================================================================================

```
                                               ## Intro ##
```

Hello, I am trying to build a node.js server, and render React with it. I have been trying to follow some online tutorials, in the process getting a little lost. I understand GET/POST routes. I know my `server.js` need to render my `index.js'. My React code runs fine with the React environment with` npm start` in the shell/terminal.

```
                                              ## The Error ##
```

My Error happens when I attempt to run my server via "nodemon server.js" in the terminal.

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:10748) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/Users/The%20core%20unit/Desktop/Code%20file%20storage/React/react-app/server.js:42
   const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Index />);
                                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
   at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:88:18)
   at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I know this Error is telling me that my `server.js` can not read the React code.

```
                                              ### server.js ###
```

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const https = require("https");
const { Server } = require("http");
const app = express();
import Index from "./src/index.js"
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
// Error List //
/*Server is starting, however not rendering any data. */

//Mongoose connection to MongoDB//
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/watchesDB",{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true});

//Mongoose Schema//
const watchesSchema = { 
    Company: String,
    Model: String,
    Year: Number
};

const Watch = mongoose.model("Watch", watchesSchema);


//Boiler Plate Code for Server//
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true 
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

// API call Routes //

//Home APi call
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Index />);
  
    const indexFile = path.resolve("./public/index.htlm");
    fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
        return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
      }
  
      return res.send(
        data.replace(`<div id="root"></div>`, `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
      );
    });
  });
  
  app.use(express.static('./build'));
  
 //Watches API call
  app.get("/watches", function(req, res){
Watch.find(function(err, foundWatches) {
    console.log(foundWatches)
});
 });


// Server listing //

app.listen(3000, function(){ 
    console.log("Server accessfully booted...") 
  });
```

```
                                           ### index.js ###
```

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Heading from "./Heading";
import Watch from "./Watch";


function Index() {
ReactDOM.render(<div>
<Heading />
<Watch /></div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
};


export default Index
```

```
      [Pic of index.js][1]

      [Pic of server.js][2]
```

Comment: IF you are not experience with server side rendering, I highly recommend to just use nextjs, with server side rendering out of the box which is very easy.

Comment: Did you build your React code? it should compile to vanilla JavaScript code.

Comment: @OrAssayag can you explain further? I have some React code that renders normally in the React environment. I also have some in my server.js.